# Javascript - changing background color opacity with time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the background color to a `.top-barz` element when I click on another element, but I would like to make that as an animation in duration of 1s. I am pretty new to javascript and not sure how to do that?

I would like to animate from change opacity of `rgba(36,36,36, .1)` to `rgba(36,36,36, 1)`

I have come up with this code and put it  into my on click function, but this is obviously not working:

```
var topBar = setInterval(function(){ topBarBackground() }, 1000);

function topBarBackground() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    $('.top-barz').css('background-color', 'rgba(36,36,36,.' + i + ')');
  }
}

clearInterval(topBar);
```

Comment: use CSS for the transition and just add a class on click with jquery

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code to get you started

JQuery

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
 $('.top-barz').addClass('new-color');
});
```

CSS

```
.top-barz {
 background-color:#000;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
 -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
 -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
 -ms-transition: background-color 1s linear;
 transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

.top-barz.new-color {
 background-color:#eee;
}
```

Obviously you would change the colors to whatever color you want for your design.

EDIT

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2fz0j7t/)

Seems to be working fine in chrome on my end

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it seems to be adding the class to the element, but the color is not changed and on inspect element in the chrome browser it doesn't show that the class is actually applied.

Comment: Could the reason be that I am using Sass and have more scss files?

Comment: See my fiddle above

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the fadeIn function of jQuery.

```
$('.top-barz').fadeIn(10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael McCoy is totally right in his comment. I would do the same as you will also benefit from GPU acceleration if you use CSS and it will make your code lighter.

This apart, your code has 2 errors:

- missing `i++`
- missing `var i`

_

```
function topBarBackground() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        $('.top-barz').css("background-color", "rgba(36,36,36,." + i + ")");
      }
}

var myVar = setInterval(function(){topBarBackground()}, 1000);
```

Anyway, drop this idea.

So to add class just do `$('.top-barz').addClass('changedColor');`

and in css:

```
.top-barz {
  background-color: rgba(36,36,36,.1);
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
.top-barz.changedColor {
  background-color: rgba(36,36,36,1);
}
```

Comment: Please accept @michael McCoy answer now that he posted his answer. He was first. Also you corrected the `++` already ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you, but for some reason the actual class is not applied to the element, it is added, but I can't see anywhere in the chrome inspector that it actually is applied?